# Prove maximum value of $(z-xy)(x-yz)(y-zx)$ is $\frac{1}{64}$ given $x,y,z \in (0,1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove maximum value of $(z-xy)(x-yz)(y-zx)$ is $\frac{1}{64}$ given $x,y,z \in (0,1)$

I can make it $\frac{1}{64}$ by setting $x,y,z = \frac{1}{2}$, but I have no idea how to show that's the maximum.

Comment: Be careful with your notation for intervals. The notation $(-1,\frac{1}{64})$ means the *open* interval from $-1$ to $\frac{1}{64}$, i.e. the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : -1 < x < \frac{1}{64}\}$. So this set does not contain the elements $-1$ and $\frac{1}{64}$. If you want to denote the *closed* interval $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : -1 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{64}\}$, use square brackets, i.e. $[-1,\frac{1}{64}]$.

Comment: I shall make the appropriate change to the question, since I only really want the maximum.

Comment: The set of maxima is invariant under permutations of the variables, so if you can show that the max is unique, then it must occur at $(1/2,1/2,1/2)$.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I must apologise for not knowing what that means. I think you're saying that each terms must be the same because they are of the same form. I also have no idea how to show the max is unique.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan No, I've got it. You're saying that if there are more than one maximum, there will $3n$ or $3n+1$ of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it happens, just yesterday I showed on this forum, 
in the process of answering
[another
stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508901), that if we fix the average
$a=\frac13(x+y+z)$ then
$$
\left( 1 - \frac{xy}{z} \right)
\left( 1 - \frac{yz}{x} \right)
\left( 1 - \frac{xz}{y} \right)
\leq (1-a)^3
$$
with equality *iff* $x=y=z=a$.
Also, by the inequality on arithmetic and geometric means
(which also figured in the proof of the $(1-a)^3$ bound),
we have $xyz \leq a^3$, again with equality *iff* $x=y=z=a$.
Multiplying these two inequalities yields
$$
(z - xy) (x - yz) (y - xz) \leq a^3 (1-a)^3 = \bigl( a(1-a) \bigr)^3,
$$
and one final application of the AM-GM inequality shows that
this is at most $(1/4)^3 = 1/64$ with equality *iff* a=1/2, **QED**.

Comment: This is in fact the end of my simpler proof to that question, but I  really don't understand that proof at all. I don't understand why we initially fix the average, for instance.

Comment: It's a reasonably common technique.  The idea is you're trying to show
the maximum occurs when all the variables are equal, and often this can
be done by showing the function gets larger when all variables are
replaced by their average.

Comment: +1 Nice. I tried showing that it was $\leq xyz(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)$ but got stuck.

Comment: I think I'd need it fleshing out a bit more to understand the hows and whys.

Comment: @stevemarvell: this is indeed a special case of general "mixing variables" technique. You can look at [these notes](http://www.awesomemath.org/wp-content/uploads/reflections/2006_6/2006_6_mixing.pdf) to see how it works in practice all just google to find better source.

Comment: The Mathematica command $$ Maximize[\{(z - x*y)*(x - y*z)*(y - z*x), 0 <= x, x <= 1, y >= 0, 
  y <= 1, z >= 0, z <= 1, x + y + z == c\}, \{x, y, z\}] $$ outputs $$1/729 (27 c^3 - 27 c^4 + 9 c^5 - c^6)  $$ for $0 < c < 3. $ That does not coinside with your answer.

Comment: I don't know how trustworthy Mathematica is on such a problem
(and since it's not open-source there's no way to find out),
but in this case its answer does coincide with what I got.  
The polynomial in parentheses factors as $c^3 (1-3c)^3$, 
and the whole thing agrees with what you get by plugging 
$x=y=z=c/3$ into $(z-xy)(x-yz)(y-zx)$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a straightforward approach. Let us put $f(x,y,z) := (-xy+z)(-yz+x)(-xz+y). $ Now we find its critical points as the solutions of the polynomial system $$\{-2y^2z^2x+y^3z+yz^3+3yzx^2-2y^2x-2z^2x+yz=0,$$ $$-2yz^2x^2+3y^2zx+z^3x+zx^3-2yz^2-2yx^2+zx=0,$$ $$-2y^2zx^2+y^3x+3yz^2x+yx^3-2y^2z-2zx^2+yx=0 \}\,(1)$$ which consists of the partial derivatives of $f$ equating to 0. Making use of [the resultant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant), we eliminate $x$ from the system with help of Maple (Of course, it can be done by hand too.):
 $$ resultant(-2*y^2*z^2*x+y^3*z+y*z^3+3*y*z*x^2-2*y^2*x-2*z^2*x+y*z, $$ $$ 2*x^2*y*z^2+x^3*z+3*x*y^2*z+x*z^3-2*x^2*y-2*y*z^2+x*z, x)$$ outputs
 $$ 4y z^3 ( 16\,y^8z^4+8\,y^6z^6+8\,y^4z^8+16\,y^8z^2+$$ $$36\,y^6z^4+25y^4z^6+7y^2
z^8-4y^8-$$ $$24\,y^6{z}^{2}+22\,{y}^{4}{z}^{4}-7\,{y}^{2}{z
}^{6}+{z}^{8}+4\,{y}^{6}-$$ $$7\,{y}^{4}{z}^{2}+9\,{y}^{2}{z}^{4}-$$ $$\left.2\,{z}^{6
}-{y}^{2}{z}^{2}+{z}^{4} \right) \,\,(2)
 $$ and $$resultant(-2*y*z^2*x^2+3*y^2*z*x+z^3*x+z*x^3-2*y*z^2-2*y*x^2+z*x,$$ $$2*x^2*y^2*z+x^3*y+x*y^3+3*x*y*z^2-2*x^2*z-2*y^2*z+x*y , x) $$ outputs $$ 16\,{y}^{2}{z}^{2} \left( {y}^{2}-{z}^{2} \right) ^{3} \left( {y}^{2}{
z}^{2}-{y}^{2}-{z}^{2}+1 \right)=$$  $$16y^2z^2 ( y^2-z^2)^3(z-1)(z+1)(y-1)(y+1)\,\,(3)
 .$$
Now we can  find all the real solutions of  equation (3) satisfying the constraints $y\ge 0, y \le 1, z\ge 0,z \le 1$: $$  [\{y = y, z = 0\}, \{y = y, z = 1\},\{y = 0, z = z\}, \{y = 1, z = z\}, \{y = z, z = z\}].$$ 
All the real solutions of  system (1) satisfying the constraints are $$\{x = 0, y = 0, z = z\}, \{x = 0, y = y, z = 0\}, \{x = x, y = 0, z = 0\}, \{x = x, y = x, z = 1\}, \{x = 1, y = y, z = y\},\{x = x, y = 1, z = x\},\{x = 1/2, y = 1/2, z = 1/2\} .$$ The Hessian of $f$ is negative definite only at the point $\{x = 1/2, y = 1/2, z = 1/2\} $ which is the only maximum point of $f$ in the cube $\{0<x,x<1,0<y,y<1,0<z,z<1\}.$

It remains to consider $f$ on the faces of the unit cube. For example, putting $x=0$, we obtain the restriction of $f$ which equals $ -y^2z^2 $ so it is nonpositive on the square $\{y \ge 0,y \le 1,z \ge 0, z\le 1\}.$ Putting $x=1$, we have the restriction of $f$ equals $\left( -y+z \right)  \left( -yz+1 \right)  \left( y-z \right)$. This also is nonpositive ibid. The behavior of $f$ on the four others is the same. Therefore, we draw the conclusion the maximum of $f$ on the unit cube  $\{0<x,x<1,0<y,y<1,0<z,z<1\}$ (which equals $\frac 1 {64}$)  is attained at $\{x = 1/2, y = 1/2, z = 1/2\} $ . See the calculations done with Maple [here](http://rapidshare.com/share/24A7D5184AF1B9ED84763ECC3F814CEA) as a PDF file.

Comment: I find it remarkable that the Mathematica command $$Maximize[\{(z - x*y)*(x - y*z)*(y - z*x), 0 <= x, x <= 1, y >= 0, 
  y <= 1, z >= 0, z <= 1\}, \{x, y, z\}] $$ produces $$ \{1/64, \{x -> 1/2, y -> 1/2, z -> 1/2\}\}, $$ mechanizing the answer done by hand.

Comment: Did it show its working out? :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a cheap way. Denote the LHS by $P$. First note that all three factors must be positive to get a positive product.

Now write $(x-yz)(y-xz)=xy(1+z^2)-(x^2+y^2)z\le xy(1+z^2)-2xyz=xy(1-z)^2$.
Multiply by $z-xy$ to get
$$
P\le xy(1-z)^2(z-xy)\,.
$$ 
Since everything is symmetric, we can just as well write
$$
P\le yz(1-x)^2(x-yz)
$$
and 
$$
P\le xz(1-y)^2(y-xz)\,.
$$ 
Multiplying these out, we get
$$
P^3\le [xyz(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)]^2P\,
$$ 
so $P\le xyz(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)$. However, $x(1-x)=\frac 14-(x-\frac 12)^2\le\frac 14$ and the same is true for the other two products.

Comment: Is it not possible that two of them could be negative?

Comment: @stevemarvell If $x-yz,y-xz<0$, then $x<yz\le y$ and $y<xz\le x$ simultaneously.

Comment: I guess not then :)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can think it in this way. Let's suppose it has a maximum (the problem ask to find it, so I think we can safely assume it has one). Now give the symmetry of the function is easy to see that if you change any of the 3 variables the function does not change. Geometrically it means you could change and of the 3 axis and the graph would not change. That means that the maximum must be at $x=y=z$. Otherwise you could exchange two axis and the graph would be changed (rotated) and the maximum would be shifted (think in 2 dimension to an oval and try to see what happens if you exchange $x$ with $y$), but the function will not change so this is not possible. Now given the fact that the $x,y,z$ are equal let's call them $x=y=z=s$, our equation will become
$$
(s-s^2)^3=\frac{1}{64}
$$
that means
$$
s-s^2=1/4
$$
and therefore given the conditions $s=1/2$.
I hope is understandable.

Comment: @ Umberto: You wrote:"That means that the maximum must be at $x=y=z$" . Could you base this claim in detail?

Comment: I think an original comment suggests that if you can prove that there is only one maxima then due to the invariance due to permutation of the terms, they must all be the same.